# How do I use clinical trials as random effects in a cox regression model stratified according to trial for an individual patient data meta-analysis?

Tags: random-effects-model, meta-analysis, clinical-trials

I am performing an individual patient data meta-analysis and pooling several trials. I have the data all combined in a single data set and want to fit it in a Cox regression model stratified according to trial, with trial identifiers used as random effects. The treatment and control are fixed effects. How should my R code look like for pooling the trials please?